# How do I compute the following double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $A = 1 + \dfrac{1}{16}v^{2}$, $B=1$, and $C=1$. If I'm given the formula

$$ S =\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{\strut AC - B^{2}} \,du \,dv $$

where $0 < u < 2\pi$ and $-1 < v < 1$, what should I get as the value of $S$? I'm not sure if I'm instead supposed to work with the formula

$$S = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\strut AC - B^{2}} \,du \,dv $$ If so, then

$$S = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{16}v^{2}} \,du \,dv $$
$$ = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{4}v \,du \,dv$$
$$ = \int_{-1}^{1} \dfrac{1}{4}v(2\pi)$$
$$ = \dfrac{2\pi}{8}v^{2} \big|_{-1}^{1} = 0? $$

Comment: $\sqrt{v^2} = |v| \neq v$

Comment: thanks! that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

In light of @NinadMunshi's comment,$$S=\frac14\int_{-1}^1|v|dv\int_0^{2\pi}du=\pi\int_0^1vdv=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$